# How to reset properly my Spinner background to my style in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-spinner

I have 7 spinners with the following style:

```
<style name="customtheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spin_bg</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
</style>
```

When a combination of spinner choices is not resulting anything I try to change the background like

```
for(int i=0;i<MySpinners.size();i++)
{
    MySpinners.get(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spin_bg_red);
}
```

but nothing happens why?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Drawable drawableBgRed = getResources ().getDrawable (R.drawable.spin_bg_red);

for(int i=0;i<MySpinners.size();i++)
{
   MySpinners.get(i).setBackground (drawableBgRed);
}
```

Comment: getDrawable is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

For `Spinner` use this:

```
// to change background of the popup list
  spinner.setPopupBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spinner_background);

// to change the `Spinner` background
  spinner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_drawable_name);
```

`spinner_background.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#ffffff" />
</shape>
```